# GridView OnRowDataBound, Cell's Text.Length

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

My datadsource is querying the table for a varchar column, that either comes out empty or comes out something like "1,2,3,4,5".

On the `RowDataBound` event I want to test if the string is not empty so I can substitute that string with an image or whatever.
But

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Length
```

returns 9 for the populated Cells (and this is correct), and returns 6 for the empty ones.

Can someone explain this to me? It's not just in this one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, always use [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) method to check for empty strings.

So, in your current problem it would be:

```
if String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Trim())
{
     // code in here would execute when the Text property is empty/null
}
```

Comment: ok, that works, but i am still very curious to find out the meaning of "6". Thanx

Comment: The empty string is replace by &nbsp; and that gives you the length 6.

Comment: ^^ Exactly. A gridview is rendered as a table and as per specs, a td cannot be empty, so &nbsp; gets added automatically.
I think you can avoid that by setting HTMLEncode to false for those fields, but that is not generally advisable.